# Add header and footer to email as Inline C#

Tags: c#, html, email, mailmessage

I have two images Header and footer of my website.

I am sending an email to Customer.

I want to add header and footer of my website to the email as inline.

In between header and footer, I want to add some information.

How can I add Images which are in Solution Explorer as inline to body of the email.

```
 var mailMessage = new MailMessage(from, userName, subject, emailBody) { IsBodyHtml = true };

            var emailClient = new SmtpClient
            {
                EnableSsl = useSsl.ToLower().Contains("true"),
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailLoginUser, emailLoginPassword),
                Host = smtpServerUrl,
                Port = int.Parse(smtpServerPort)
            };
            emailClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can embed resources in a `MailMessage` using `AlternateView`. The code is quite understandable. I assumed that `from` and `userName` are strings, creating instances of `MailAddress`:

```
public static void SendMail(string from, string userName, string subject, string emailBody)
{
    string htmlBody = string.Format("<html><body><img src=\"cid:Header\" /><br />{0}<br /><img src=\"cid:Footer\" /></body></html>", emailBody);
    AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, Encoding.Default, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

    // Create a LinkedResource object for each embedded image
    LinkedResource header = new LinkedResource("Header.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
    header.ContentId = "Header";

    LinkedResource footer = new LinkedResource("Footer.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
    header.ContentId = "Footer";

    avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(header);
    avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(footer);


    // Add the alternate views instead of using MailMessage.Body
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(userName));
    mailMessage.Subject = subject;
    mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);

    // Address and send the message
    var emailClient = new SmtpClient
    {
        EnableSsl = useSsl.ToLower().Contains("true"),
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailLoginUser, emailLoginPassword),
        Host = smtpServerUrl,
        Port = int.Parse(smtpServerPort)
    };
    emailClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```